# Unity Editor - Call a method from a ScriptableObject from its own custom Editor

Tags: unity

I have a class like this:

```
public class NoiseMap : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now I am building its custom editor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(NoiseMap))]
public class NoiseMapEditor : Editor
{

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        // How to call Hello() ???

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

}
```

I would like to get the value of the method `Hello`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Presumably you already read the docs and tried casting the [targetObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject-targetObject.html) to your type? Did that not have the expected effect?

Answer (score 2):

you're really close. You just need to get a target reference to the main script like so:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    NoiseMap noiseMap = (NoiseMap)target;

    //then you can reference it like so:

    noiseMap.Hello();
}
```